# Bodybuilding.com's New Paywall

Tags: discussion

Recently, it seems that [bodybuilding.com](https://www.bodybuilding.com/en-CA/index) has been putting more and more of its content behind the *BodyFit Plus* paywall.

For example, I was looking at [this answer](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/15589/31284) while searching up some ideas for hamstring exercises. All 7 links guide me to bodybuilding.com but I'm just met with a [page](https://www.bodybuilding.com/exercises/barbell-hip-thrust) that has some generic wiki information and then subscription options.

[image]

I also used to look at bodybuilding.com for some workout routines and even those seem to behind a paywall now. Has anyone else noticed this? I feel like these links just aren't useful anymore.

I might look for more examples but I don't think you can search questions for the embedded links.

Answer (score 4):

> I might look for more examples but I don't think you can search questions for the embedded links.

Actually, you can: use the `url:` search option mentioned in the [Help Center](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/help/searching) (near the bottom, under 'Miscellaneous Operators'). [This search](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3Abodybuilding.com) shows there are currently 294 posts on the main site with potentially less useful links.

---

As to how to replace these links: 294 posts is a lot of work, but I guess many posts link to the same exercises. I could try to generate a list of links and how often they're used; that requires a few lines of coding against the [Stack Exchange API](https://api.stackexchange.com/). I hope you can find one or more websites with links that can serve as alternatives; maybe one of the regulars here has ideas about that. Then, editing the links is again a tedious job, but it's possible to automate some of it. I have a bit of experience with [such an operation on German Language Stack Exchange](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1506/15821), though that was a bit easier since all I had to do was replace the domain (the rest of the URL remained the same).

Comment: I did not know about the URL search; that's very handy. Unfortunately, automating it won't be possible. Links to exercises on bodybuilding.com could probably move over to ExRx or an equivalent database. Some of the bodybuilding.com links are to locked programs (likely no real equivalent) or articles (which could be OK still).